# Response is null

Tags: ios, objective-c

My response is shown null. But when you enter the url in your  browser it shows  1. But in my code it returns 0.
The url is http://boomagift.ramansingla.com/forgotpassword.php?email=nihal@gmail.com. I would really appreciate it if someone could help me out. I am new to iOS .

```
+(NSDictionary *)forgotpassword:(NSString *)email
{
    NSDictionary *dict=[[NSDictionary alloc]init];


    NSString *urlStr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://boomagift.ramansingla.com/forgotpassword.php?email=%@",email];
    NSLog(@"%@",urlStr);

    NSMutableURLRequest *request=[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlStr]];
    dict  =  [self sendRequest:request];
    NSLog(@"%@",dict);

    return dict;
}

+(NSDictionary *)sendRequest:(NSMutableURLRequest *)request
{
    NSHTTPURLResponse *response;
    NSError *error;
    NSData *responseData;
    responseData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    if(responseData&&[responseData length])
    {

       NSDictionary *dictionary=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:&error];
        return dictionary;
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *noInternetAlert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Boom A GIft" message:@"Server Error" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [noInternetAlert show];
        noInternetAlert=nil;
        return nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: if I run this URL  in browser I got the answer **1**, its is correct or u get the response is something else

Comment: yes i m getting response is null in my code and in browser it shown 1

Comment: In browser it is 0 please check

Comment: please check http://boomagift.ramansingla.com/forgotpassword.php?email=nihal@gmail.com

Comment: can you check what is responseData value?

Comment: data getting from the mentioned URL is not in JSON format. JSON format is key value pair and JSONObjectWithData:responseData can parse only JSON not raw String. You are getting raw string from server.

NSDictionary *dictionary=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:&error];

Comment: @aBilal17 my response data is <31>

Comment: It should be json man.
to check weather data is in json format or not please use http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

Answer (score 1):

The response data is no valid JSON, because its top item is a number, not a Collection (list or object).

> An object that may be converted to JSON must have the following
>   properties:
>
> - The top level object is an `NSArray` or `NSDictionary`.
> - All objects are instances of `NSString`, `NSNumber`, `NSArray`,
>     `NSDictionary`, or `NSNull`.
> - All dictionary keys are instances of `NSString`.
> - `Numbers` are not `NaN` or infinity.

You can configure the serializer to accept non-collection objects at top level with the `options` paramater.

```
enum {
  NSJSONReadingMutableContainers = (1UL << 0),
  NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves = (1UL << 1),
  NSJSONReadingAllowFragments = (1UL << 2)
};
typedef NSUInteger NSJSONReadingOptions;
```

> `NSJSONReadingAllowFragments`
>
> Specifies that the parser should allow
>   top-level objects that are not an instance of `NSArray` or `NSDictionary`.
>
> Available in OS X v10.7 and later.

BTW: returning `nil` (not `NULL`) with an error-out parameter is not joking, but a hint, what the problem is. ;-)

Comment: Please mark it as correct answer to let others find it.